# Tray to hold a big turkey

Tags: turkey

I have a 40 pounds Turkey. I want to cook it on the oven. Where can i get a tray big enought to hold it. The ones in walmart are not big enough.

Answer (score 3):

That's a big bird!

I'd recommend buying something like the [Nordic Ware Commercial Baker's Sheet](http://amzn.to/2kcyAts), or picking something large off the list of [Turkey Roasting Trays](http://amzn.to/2jKpXp4) available on the linked list.

Another option is to break the turkey down before cooking, and then you won't need a big tray!